# Loop is executing infinite times

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, programming

I am working with an [ATmega32-A](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8155.pdf) microcontroller. Using USART communication, I am displaying data on monitor and am using switch case to select different commands. In one of the commands I have written the following code:

```
 case(DATA):

  init_io();
  statusreg = AD7798_8(0x40, 0xFF); 
  printf("status register %02x\r\n", statusreg); 

  if (statusreg != 0x80) 
      printf("unexpected power on status %02x\r\n", statusreg); 

  while(1){
            while ((statusreg & 0x80) != 0);                 // wait till ADC is ready 
            adc = AD7798_16(0x58, 0xFFFF);                   // read register 
            printf("ADC value is %04x\r\n", adc); 
          } 
  Command=0;
  break;
```

But the above code is printing the ADC value infinite times. I have changed the while loop to the following

```
   while(1){
            while ((statusreg & 0x80) != 0);                 // wait till ADC is ready 
            adc = AD7798_16(0x58, 0xFFFF);                   // read register 
            printf("ADC value is %04x\r\n", adc); 
          }
```

After that it is printing only once, but does not accept any more commands. I have to re-build if I want to enter any other command. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Am I the only person who can't see any difference between the two `while(1)` loops? Also, the *inner* `while` loop will execute either 0 or an infinite number of iterations, depending on the value in `statusreg` coming into it. This is the same problem we addressed [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/44747/11683).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `while(1){}` loop never exits, (unless you have a `break` inside) so it will always stick there. Why do you need the `while(1)` anyway? It looks like you are only reading once from the ADC.
If you do want to loop more than once, you need to add a condition to equal 0 when whatever it is you want to do inside has finished.

Comment: Ha, ignore my last comment, I misread all the text.

Comment: The while(1) looks entirely unnecessary anyways since it's going to lock up until the ADC is available.  It's not like he's timing out and retrying things.